# NodeJs - Check if child process started successfully

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, process, nodes

I have a script `Start.js` which is starting another script `Server.js` using `shelljs`.

`Server.js` contains a express server which should run at `process.env.PORT`.

`Start.js` should print out if the server was started correctly or not.

```
const process = shell.exec(`node Server.js`, {
            async: true,
            env: {
                PORT: 3000
            }
        }) as ChildProcess;

// how to detect that server was successfully started?
```

How can this script detect if the server was successfully started?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to write to stdout in Server.js, and listen to stdout in the exec callback function.

```
// Shell.js docs
exec('some_long_running_process', function(code, stdout, stderr) {
  console.log('Exit code:', code);
  console.log('Program output:', stdout);
  console.log('Program stderr:', stderr);
});

// Example
exec('node Server.js', function(code, stdout, stderr) {
  console.log('Exit code:', code);
  console.log('Program output:', stdout); // could print: 'server up!'
  console.log('Program stderr:', stderr);
});
```